# Can't use Tableau on a EMR Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark, odbc, tableau-api

I have a client that wants to use Tableau on their EMR Spark cluster.

The documentation seems straightforward but I'm getting errors when I try to connect.

Here is the setup:

1. EMR cluster's master doesn't have a public IP, but from the Tableau desktop EC2 instance I am able to ping and `telnet` into the port 10001 where `thrift` is running
2. I am able to test `thrift` with `beeline` and it connects fine
3. I am not using SSL or authentication given the limit access the cluster has
4. I have installed both data direct 8.0 and simbaodbc

I'm using `emr-5.13.0`, the Hadoop distribution is Amazon 2.8.3 and the Spark version is 2.3.0.

The error is

```
Unable to connect to the ODBC Data Source. Check that the necessary drivers are installed and that the connection properties are valid.

[Simba][ThriftExtension] (5) Error occurred while contacting server: No more data to read.. This could be because you are trying to establish a non-SSL connection to an SSL-enabled server.

Unable to connect to the server "IP". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database."
```

I simply followed the documentation provided by Tableau which says to install the driver only (not mess with ODBC), then us it in Tableau. I have verified that I have set no SSL and no authentication before trying to connect. I also verified by running Datagrip and doing a query from the Tableau EC2 instance, which works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved the issue by ignoring the documentation and just setting up the odbc driver, then choosing it instead of sparksql as a source.